# How to rename a directory in PHP to a Unique ID?

Tags: php

I am a bit familiar with PHP, although I am trying to work with a PHP script that I haven't really done before:

```
$src = "/home/user/public_html/test1";
$dest = "/home/user/public_html/test2";
shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");
echo "Directory successfully created."; //output when done
rename("$dest","uniqid();");
```

This script is supposed to copy the files of a directory so that the newly created directory will be /home/user/public_html/test2/test1.

However, because this script is supposed to be used dynamically, I would like the rename function to rename the $dest to a uniqid(); function.

Can anyone compile a script for me that can do this or provide instructions on how to??

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has built-in functions to do this. No need to access the shell. It's one quick search in the docs ;)

Comment: You don't have to copy and then rename, just copy and in the destination use the directory you want it to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the idea here, but you should change this `rename("$dest","uniqid();");` to `rename($dest,uniqid());`. Get rid of the quotes and semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```
$info = array();
$info['src'] = "/home/user/public_html/test1";
$info['dest'] = "/home/user/public_html/".uniqid();

// another thought for dest name if you want to easily sort it and guarantee unique-ness
// $info ['dest'] = "/home/user/public_html/".uniqid(time().'.'.microtime(true).'.', true);

// make sure directory doesn't exist or else overwriting will occur
$info['dir_test'] = is_dir($dest);
if(!$info['dir_test'])
{
    $info['copy_result'] = copy($info['src'], $info['dest']);
    if($info['copy_result'])
    {
        $info['text_result'] = 'copy success :)';
    }
    else
    {
        $info['text_result'] = 'copy failed :(';
    }
}
else
{
    $info['text_result'] = 'destination already exists! - '.$destination;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($info, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: This code does not remove the old directory.

Comment: @Michael Did I misunderstand something? `This script is supposed to copy the files of a directory`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Missed that part.

Comment: @Michael It seems like OP might be doing some sort of backup/version control procedure so they need to keep the old files as well :)

Comment: Yeah i got confused by the title. I assumed that he wants to rename a folder as mentioned in the title. Then he would also have to remove the old one if he uses the `copy()` function. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, this helps because I am building a PHP application where users get their own space to use, and I needed a script that copies are made from the source directory.

Comment: I just tried this script, it didn't work unforunately. It showed an error that "copy failed :(".

Comment: I fixed a part of this, and it works. Thanks guys!

Comment: No problem! I added in some debugging stuff you can check out as well. What fixed it?

Comment: I used the shell command as listed above merged with the values for the $dest. Once again, thanks.